# How do I assign my variable to the string response of my API?

Tags: python, node.js, json, rest

I am sending a post request to a Python flask api. I am returning a 200 and the body of the response logs in the console correctly. However when I try to pass it to the "response" variable to store the variable it doesn't assign.

I've tried to log the response variable and see what is actually passed into it. If I try to log it to the console in the request call it shows it successfully has a string. But when I log it to the console outside of the request it shows as undefined?

This is my Node.js doing the call

```
function handleMessage(sender_psid, received_message) {

let response;

request({
  "uri": "http://localhost:8090/givenMessage",
  "method": "POST",
  "json": received_message
}, (err, res, body) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('message sent to python!')
    console.log(typeof body)
    var string = JSON.stringify(body);
    var objectValue = JSON.parse(string);
    response = body; //parse the json body to string keep body in
  } else {
    console.error("Unable to send message to python:" + err);
  }
});


// Check if the message contains text
/*if (received_message.text) {    

  // Create the payload for a basic text message
  response = {
    "text": `You sent the message: "${received_message.text}".`
  }
}  */

// Sends the response message
callSendAPI(sender_psid, response);    
}
```

This is my python post handler

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__) #create the app server to recieve post

@app.route('/givenMessage', methods = ['POST'])
def postJsonHandler():
    print (request.is_json)
    content = request.get_json()
    print (content)
    return 'JSON posted'

 app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8090)
```

Right now the response variable is just undefined when I pass it to the callSendAPI method. I'd like for it to have the string output 'JSON posted' from my python post call

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I answered it. The post request was slow so the response variable didn't have time to get assigned. It was asynchronously calling. I jsut put my method inside the if statement to wait for the post response